# Define a custom accuracy in Keras to ignore samples with a particular label

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing to you because I have a problem, the same as the question in the link below that has not been answered.

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270722/how-to-define-a-custom-accuracy-in-keras-to-ignore-samples-with-a-particular-gol/53093965?noredirect=1#comment93084625_53093965)

I have defined a loss function that excludes all pixel = 0:

```
def ignore_unknown_xentropy(ytrue, ypred):
    return (1-ytrue[:, :, :, 0]) * K.categorical_crossentropy(ytrue, ypred)
```

I noticed that during the training accuracy is distorted, going to consider the pixels equal to zero that I had previously excluded.

There is a way to define a custom metric to exclude zero pixels on `y_true` from its calculation?

I'm using this approach, that is to calculate the accuracy for each relevant label and add them, but it does not give me reliable results:

```
def single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, class_id):
    class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
    class_id_preds = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    accuracy_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_preds, class_id), 'int32')
    class_acc_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, class_id_preds), 'int32') * accuracy_mask
    class_acc = K.sum(class_acc_tensor) / K.maximum(K.sum(accuracy_mask), 1)
    return class_acc

def custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, 1) + single_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, 2)
```

And my `ytrue` is a one-hot encoded mask.

Comment: What is your `ytrue` (what shape, dimension description). I suppose you are classifying each pixel (a segmentation problem), right?

Comment: My ytrue is a one-hot encoded mask, you're right, it's a segmentation problem, so I classify every pixel, but those at zero must contribute zero both in the calculation of the loss and in the calculation of the accuracy

Answer (score 0):

Is there no way to achieve this just with class weighting?
Set 0 for the class you are not interested in?
I may have misunderstood, but this approach lept out to me (ignore class zero):

```
class_weights = {0.0:0.2,0.2:0.2:0.2}
history=model.fit(x=in_train,y=target_train,class_weight=class_weights,
              validation_data=.... etc
```

Comment: I'm using a huge training set, so I can not load it into memory and I opted for fit_generator () (maybe it's not the best method I'm not expert) and when I set class_weight = {0: 0.0, 1: 0.5, 2: 0.5} it give me this error:                           
ValueError: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.